# SQL performance for select from where result of table

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to ask for performance of SQL. This is my query:

```
Select 
    A.code
   ,A.name
   ,(Select
        B.price
     From B
     Where B.card = A.card
     And B.quote = A.quote)
   ,(Select
        B.quantity
     From B
     Where B.card = A.card
     And B.quote = A.quote)
From A
Where A.flag = '0'
  And A.date = '2016/09/02'
```

Something like this. Is it good performance query? Is will slow if data will big amount. How should I make query for more good performance?

Sorry for my poor English and thanks in advance

Comment: You have correlated subqueries in your `SELECT` statement.  So this might run slow for large tables.

Comment: Not taking performance into accout this query is 1.) hard to read and 2.) error-prone since it will fail when the subselect returns more than one row. In your case you should use a `JOIN`

Comment: Read this: http://www.sqlservice.se/sql-server-performance-death-by-correlated-subqueries/

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @piet.t  Thank u for your comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is Oracle 11g run on SI Object Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, faster in time execute

```
Select 
    A.code
   ,A.name
   ,B.price
   ,B.quantity

From A
left join B on B.card = A.card And B.quote = A.quote
Where A.flag = '0'
And A.date = '2016/09/02
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better to go for a left join rather than correlated subquery if you are querying the same table multiple times...

```
Select 
    A.code
   ,A.name
   ,B.Price
   ,B.quantity

From A
LEFT JOIN B
 on B.card = A.card
     And B.quote = A.quote
Where A.flag = '0'
And A.date = '2016/09/02'
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your answer.